# Finishing moves when an enemy is on the ground

Tags: gears-of-war-3

Just started playing Gears of War 3 online - and I saw that when an opponent is on the floor there is a possibility to make several finish moves.  Some of the cool stuff:

1. Pickng up an opponent and using him as a shield.
2. Tearing his arm and beating him with it.

How can I perform these (and any other) finishing moves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These finishing moves are known as executions. You can perform these on a downed enemy by standing next to them and holding Y. There are also weapon specific executions that can be performed by executing an opponent while having a specific weapon active.

See this page on the Gears Wiki for a detailed list of the different executions and how to perform them.

http://gearsofwar.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Gears_of_War_Executions#Gears_of_War_3_Executions

Comment: Picking up an opponent and using him as a shield is not an execution, and you do it by hitting A.

Comment: @IanPugsley While not necessarily an execution in the strictest sense, using an opponent as a meat shield does kill them, and it can lead to the bag-and-tag execution.